# What happens with an electric field changing at a constant rate vs a non-constant rate?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electric-fields

A changing E field in one coordinate system is a static B field in a different coordinate system, and vice versa, yes?  But does it matter whether the rate of change is constant or not?

Specifically, I'm wondering: if a constant current (which of course causes a changing E field) results in a magnetic,l field, but also a changing magnetic field is a static electric field in a different reference frame, does a time-vary current result in a *changing* magnetic field instead of a.constant one?

Comment: Are you familiar with Maxwell's equations? These detail the entirety of the electrodynamical systems.